# What do we know about $\text{P}^\text{NE}$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, complexity-classes, nexp

I have a $\text{NEXP}$-hard problem, that can be solved by a $\text{NEXP}^\text{NP}$ algorithm using a single oracle call.
So from [Hemaspaandra](http://ecommons.library.cornell.edu/bitstream/1813/6617/1/86-777.pdf) we know it is in $\text{P}^\text{NE}$, giving us
$\text{NEXP}$-completeness under Cook-reductions.

- Are there (more or less) natural problems complete for $\text{P}^\text{NE}$?
- What do we know about the space between $\text{NEXP}$ and $\text{P}^\text{NE}$?
- Anything else that might help to sharpen this result (to Karp-reductions)?